# GitLab: Unable to fork my own project

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to fork one of my private projects in GitLab, But when I press the fork button I'll receive this:

> No available namespaces to fork the project. 
>   You must have permission to create a project in a namespace before forking.

But I have Master privilege in the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, seems like you have to create a group in order to do that

Comment: how does one create a group?

Answer (score 7):

1. From the top, blue navigation menu, go to `Groups > Your Groups`,
2. Click the `New group` button on the top right corner,
3. Type in the details of your new group,
4. Click the `Create group` button.

On the `Members` page of your new group, manage your members. Your account would probably already be added.

Now you can fork that project.

Answer (score 3):

From https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25805:

> For anyone running into this question: What I did is first fork a
>   repository to another name space (group or other), then rename the
>   project and also the repository in the Advanced Settings. Then
>   transfer the project back to the original namespace (group).